# Why does Safari seem to have a problem with css position:fixed?

Tags: css, safari, cross-browser, fixed, css-position

I am working on this site: http://www.mywebclass.org/~jeff/ . A large percent of the ui is built with position:fixed;. In all the browsers except Safari it renders fine. But in Safari it is all messed up. Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have `position:fixed` on a few elements but you haven't set any of `top`, `left`, `right`, or `bottom` to tell the browser where they should be positioned. The browser will be left to guess (within limits) what you mean if you don't specify the position and different browsers will guess different things. The solution is to add `left` and `top` properties to all your `position:fixed` elements.

Comment: @chromedude: "different browsers will guess different things". Opera, for example, doesn't even show your lightbulb.